# Installing godag on ubuntu

Tags: compiling

On Ubuntu/Linux, I did this:

```
hg clone https://godag.googlecode.com/hg/ godag
```

and after this:

```
go run mk.go install
```

and it gives me this error:

```
up 2 date: utilz/stringbuffer 
up 2 date: utilz/walker 
up 2 date: utilz/stringset 
up 2 date: utilz/global 
up 2 date: utilz/handy
up 2 date: utilz/say
up 2 date: utilz/timer
up 2 date: parse/gopt
up 2 date: cmplr/dag
up 2 date: cmplr/gdmake
up 2 date: cmplr/compiler
up 2 date: start/main
linking  : /usr/lib/go/bin/gd
cannot create /usr/lib/go/bin/gd: No such file or directory
2014/10/05 11:05:40 [ERROR] exit status 1
exit status 1
```

Tried `sudo go run mk.go -B=gcc install` but I get the same error. Googled the problem and tried all possible combinations, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error maybe because the directory `/usr/lib/go/bin/` does not exist:

```
$ sudo go run mk.go install
compiling: utilz/stringbuffer
# ...
compiling: start/main
linking  : /usr/lib/go/bin/gd
cannot create /usr/lib/go/bin/gd: No such file or directory
2014/10/02 19:14:51 [ERROR] exit status 1
exit status 1
$ ls /usr/lib/go/
doc/         favicon.ico  lib/         pkg/         src/         
$ sudo mkdir /usr/lib/go/bin
$ sudo go run mk.go install
up 2 date: utilz/stringbuffer
# ...
up 2 date: start/main
linking  : /usr/lib/go/bin/gd
```

Just create the directory using `sudo mkdir /usr/lib/go/bin` and you should be fine.